# Как в Kohana 3.2 кэшировать изображения?

Tags: php, kohana

Именно кэшировать на стороне сервера. Рисунки "оригиналы" у меня хранятся в Mongo gridFS, оттуда дергаю, режу и хочу кэшировать на стороне сервера, чтобы каждый раз не резать изображения.
P.S.: Сделал реализацию кеширования на Mongo gridFS, т.е. обработанные изображения храню в базе, но хотелось бы узнать реализацию и на Kohana

Comment: Хм. А можно уточнить вопрос.
Обычно, отдача картинок - это работа web сервера, кэшированием занимается клиент (браузер). От программы (в данном случае коханы) требуется только подготовить файл (обрезать, уменьшить) и положить в специальную директорию. Есть исключения, например, капча, но это другая история.

Comment: @dimmaq ответил выше